# No one likes change/changes/changing

Tags: grammar

1. No one likes change (but babies in diapers).
2. No one likes (diaper) changes.
3. No one likes (diaper) changing.

A. Why does #1 use the word change without articles?
B. How does each differ from each other meaningwise?
C. Which one is most natural?

Comment: Where did the sentences come from? A book (which one), film, are they your own? This would help to answer the question (I would use an article in the first one if it is about diapers, but not if it is about change in general and you added the diaper part).

Comment: Probably *No-one likes changing diapers* is the most natural phrasing. Certainly that would be the case with *No-one likes ironing socks* (where I suggest *no-one* would normally say *No-one likes sock ironing*). I think the *default* construction is verb modifying the "real" noun *(diapers, socks)*, rather than using the noun attributively to modify another (gerund) noun *(changing, ironing)*. That latter format is normally reserved for more "elevated" activities, or ones which have just entered common usage by constant repetition *(dish-washing, bird watching, etc.)*.

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers. Can you elaborate on the meaning of your "elevated"?

Comment: @JoeKim I haven't answered as I'm still not 100% sure what you're looking for. We can answer A and B pretty well, and I think we have, but for C we need to know what meaning you're actually trying to express. If you just want to say that no one enjoys the act of changing a baby's diaper, then FumbleFingers is correct: no one likes changing diapers.

Comment: @DCShannon um.. It is getting difficult to percept and even explain it as I am not sure as well. In this case, can you just explain what each sentence means as it is in regards to the usage of no article, plural, and gerund. Do not try to figure out what I try to mean, but just look at the sentence itself and if one can have more than one meaning, then pleace let me know all the possibilities. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> No one likes change (but babies in diapers).

This is a witticism, a garden-path joke of sorts. The first part of the statement is simply an acknowledgement of a human condition: *people don't like change*. (That also explains why there is no article, when we speak of change in the general sense, we don't usually use an article.)

The parenthetical part is a humorous exception, and a pun on the word *change*: babies like to have their diapers changed, because they don't like sitting in soiled diapers.

> No one likes (diaper) changes.
>   No one likes (diaper) changing.

I agree with the first comment under your question; these would be easier to interpret if you told us where you got them from. However, it doesn't take too many times changing a diaper to realize it's not a pleasant experience. These sentences simply emphasize that no one enjoys changing a diaper – it's not one of the pleasant parts of parenthood. Either version is grammatical, and it's almost impossible to pick a preferred wording without any further context.

Comment: Thank you,  J.R. Then what would be proper contexts for changes and changing? With some simple examples, can you also explain how the two are exactly different within your context?

Comment: I think that "no one likes diaper changes" means no one likes having their diaper changed, whereas "no one likes diaper changing" means no one likes changing the diapers of others. Couldn't say why.

Comment: Thank you, DCShannon. You have perfactly explained well.

Comment: @DCShannon, FumbleFingers have suggested above that he would rather change the position and that way is most natural: changing diapers. What is your opinion about this? Are the two forms equally useable, or the elevated something, according to FF, exists behind the option 3?

Comment: @Joe - You have to go back to Lucky's comments before we can talk about what FF's said. "Equally usuable"? It's hard to answer that when we don't know what you're trying to say, or how you're trying to say it. If you're only trying to state the obvious, then "no one likes changing diapers" is perhaps the best way to say it. But if you're trying to do more – to form a pun, to say it poetically, to say it humorously, to make a maxim, for example – then the straightforward way may not be the best way. If I was trying to be funny, I might say: *No one likes diaper changes – except for the baby.*

Comment: @J.R. to answer you, I can only say, I don't know. These are my sentences and I wanted to know when you would pick each differnt format to express "what". I do not know the boundary as much as you don't know. If You could put all the variables on the table, and guid me cook more similar but different sentences without needing to ask you what it means, that would best. So far I have understood technical straightforward sides from DCShannon, and from you that both noun forms are for "only" something twisted. But I guess this isn't true for using noun forms, but it has to do with something else,

Comment: because I don't use the word water or change to be funny. Now with this picture can you explain what are possible sentences and how each differ from each other, and if the noun with no article and nouns of single and plural mean a pun, how could that work (is it because all noun forms are used this way).